# Unable to execute pyinstaller compiled binary for Windows

Tags: python-3.5, pyinstaller

I wrote a script in Python 3.5.2 and compiled it to a binary on Mac which works fine.

I then compiled the script on my Win 7 machine `pyinstaller --onefile script.py`. There were no errors during the compilation, however its execution fails.

Below is the full traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "c:\users\support\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader
\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "c:\users\support\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader
\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 92, in __get__
  File "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
  File "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
ImportError: No module named 'queue'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 5, in <module>
    import support
  File "c:\users\support\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader
\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "support.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "c:\users\support\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader
\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
  File "c:\users\support\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader
\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "c:\users\support\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader
\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "c:\users\support\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader
\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\requests\compat.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "c:\users\support\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader
\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "c:\users\support\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader
\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "c:\users\support\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader
\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 92, in __get__
  File "site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
  File "site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
ImportError: No module named 'queue'
Failed to execute script myscript
```

I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to pass `--hidden-import=queue` argument to pyinstaller.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes,decode errors were found.
For example: GBK cann't decode.some special code : .\?-_... .Check your code!